# Do something while keeping a button pressed

Tags: java, android, button, onlongclicklistener

I want to keep a button pressed and WHILE pressed it will do something. I firstly confused it with onLongClick() but this method will perform an action after long pressed. Tried everything but it doesn't work. Does anyone has an idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for something more along the lines of the [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Set the listener on your button and listen for the MotionEvent.ActionDown event found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

kick off your code when you receive [ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN), and stop it when your receive [ACTION_UP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP).

Comment: This is my actual problem to be precise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830916/send-data-to-arduino-as-long-as-the-button-is-being-pressed