# Send data to arduino as long as the button is being pressed

Tags: android, arduino, ontouchlistener, motionevent, android-developer-api

I want to send data to an arduino mega 2560 as long as a button is being pressed and when that button is released it will stop sending informations. I am using onTouchListener with MotionEvent constants. But when I run this on my phone I press the button and it sends data even though after a while I release it. Where am I being wrong here?

```
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.left1: // check what button is pressed

        while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            bt.sendData("1"); // while pressing the button it sends data

        } 
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            // when it stops, do nothing

        }

        break;

    }

    return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in infinite loop `while(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)` that you start upon receiving the first event.

`OnTouchListener` is called for each event that is dispatched to view, down and up are separate events and event does not change while being processed.

So to solve your problem - you need to send data from a separate thread.
Start it on `ACTION_DOWN` and also have a flag that will be modified on `ACTION_UP` to indicate thread to exit.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the flag of `bt.sendData` to `false` when button is released which seems to be absent in your code.

It's like you open tap for water but forget to close the tap when you are finished. Hope it helps

Comment: I am not an expert and therefor I couldn't understand you very well. What do you mean by set the flag to false? And how can I achieve it?

Comment: You're right about "forget to close the tap" concept, but arguments to `bt.sendData` have to little to do with it, since it is being called in an infinite loop

Comment: I think Vasfed have given the same explanation using code and it seems that it would work like a charm